# TPS63070 buck-boost not bucking or boosting correctly

Tags: voltage-regulator, step-down, buck-boost, step-up

Can someone check my layout? I am using TPS63070 buck-boost regulator and I would like to get 4.7 V output at TP12 but, I am getting 11.5 V which is wrong and I don't know why.

Base on the Datasheet R1=R2(Vo/Vref-1) =>
R1=34k(4.7/0.8-1) => R1=165k, R2=34k

Could someone let me know why?

FB: 1.9 mV  Vin: 4.7 V. Vout: 5.28 V

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The TPS63070 is internally compensated and intended for use with inductors from 1uH to 2.2uH and certain values of output capacitance.  See table 3 in the datasheet.  There's no way to know without running an open-loop gain/phase curve to know if it will be stable with lower values of inductance.  Have you looked at the output on a 'scope?  It could be oscillating.  What's your load?

Comment: What do you measure at FB and FB2?

Comment: FB is 1.9V when the voltage is 11

Comment: @John: I have no load on the output(I even try to put resistor but same) but when I look at the output on the scope it is smooth 11.5V. Regarding the inductor, in the manual page 18, it said it recommended, but you can find it with above formual

Comment: schematic seems fine, could the problem be in the layout? or in the assembly process since you hand solder it..

Comment: @amir In that case measuring the voltage at the FB pin will narrow the problem down.  If it's equal to Vref then the circuit is working but your layout (feedback point and/or grounding) is possibly the problem.

Comment: @John thank for response. My Fb is not equal vref of 0.8v, it  is around 1.9v. I also follow the layout guideline in datasheet. I don't understand wht is stepping up the voltage instead of down. I want 4.7v output and input power is 5.8. Thanks

Comment: Are you measuring the FB voltage right at the IC?  Right between pins 6 & 4? (Not out at the junction of the FB resistors to some local ground).  What's the saturation current limit of your inductor (or P/N and datasheet link)?

Comment: @John. I am reading FB voltage from pin 5 of the chip which is 1.89.
I am using MLF2012DR33KT000 inductor, I already put an order for 1.5uH inductor LQM21PN1R5MC0D

Comment: @amir Oh, right, sorry, it is pin 5 not 6.  With that much error it's pretty obvious that ground shift isn't the problem anyway.  More likely there's some layout or connection problem, or the inductor is causing issues.  Can you post a link to the inductor datasheet or at least let us know the saturation current rating?

Comment: @John the inductor datasheet https://product.tdk.com/info/en/catalog/datasheets/inductor_commercial_standard_mlf2012_en.pdf

Comment: That's a pretty small inductor, rated 250mA but with 0.4 ohms of max ESR.  No info on saturation characteristics.  Still, with no load it should work.  I would conclude you have a bad solder connection somewhere, a layout issue, or a mis-wire somewhere.  The suggestion below of a bad solder connection on the IC itself could very well be the problem.  Maybe one of the ground pins is not well connected.

Comment: All I need is 50mA out of the regulator so that why I choose this

Comment: @amir, I am afraid you again have chosen a wrong inductor for the job, low current, multilayer design. The datasheet, however, uses "shielded power inductor" XFL4020-1.5µH. I am afraid the selection is not based on how much average current your load takes, but how much transient current (during switch time) the inductor can tolerate without saturation. I am afraid you will have the same result.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have the correct resistors in place for the feedback circuit. The only thing that appears out of place is the 330nH inductor. Looks like they have a 1.5uH in the data sheet. It should still technically regulate to the voltage you need though..

Have you soldered this part by hand? I've had issues in the past where I've soldered a part incorrectly and then it fails to regulate. (either by damage or bad connections) Always good to check on a development board if you can. TI's are dirt cheap and worth every penny.

Also, is there anything connected to that rail that could a source of back powering? It appears you said you have a power source at about 5.8V but if you have any other power sources in the system I would definitely take a look at that too.

Comment: I solder it by hand but I will take look at it Thanks

Comment: try measuring the voltage on the FB pin

Comment: @Jared I have two power supply battery and dc voltage but if I even i use one if it still getting same voltage 10.5-11.5

Comment: Did you make your own footprint? Definitely go back and cross check your footprint to the data sheet. More details on the batteries would be useful. 

Also without seeing the rest of the schematic it's up to you to determine if there are any back-powering paths. (think pull-ups, FETs, diodes, etc) If you're measuring the battery voltage through the IC, make sure there's no feasible path that the battery voltage could take.

Comment: Yes, I made my own footprint and follow the datasheet(attached). I even only solder aboard just with regulator and its parts and give a DC 5v(power supply ) at C1 still I am getting 11v at TP12. One thing I Figure out is the PG pin is low which means "output voltage below power good threshold, in thermal shutdown or input /output overvoltage protection active" base on the datasheet PG 11